# How to deal with "List<T>.Add(default)" correctly?

Tags: c#, nullable, .net-4.8

Consider the following code compiled in a `#nullable` context and using **.Net Framework 4.8**:

```
public sealed class Test<T>
{
    public Test()
    {
        _data.Add(default); // warning CS8604: Possible null reference argument for parameter 'item' in 'void List<T>.Add(T item)'.
    }

    public T Item => _data[0];

    readonly List<T> _data = new List<T>();
}
```

This code causes Warning CS8604, as indicated by the comment.

It is *not* possible to fix the code by using `T?` without constraining `T` to be `class`:

```
public sealed class Test<T>
{
    public Test()
    {
        _data.Add(default);
    }

    public T? Item => _data[0];                // error CS8627: A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type

    readonly List<T?> _data = new List<T?>();  // error CS8627: A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type
}
```

I cannot add a "struct" or "class" type constraint because this code is actually in a `PriorityQueue<T>` class that is already used in a lot of places with both value and reference types.

So what I've done for now is just suppress the message like so:

```
public Test()
{
    _data.Add(default!); // Note the "!"
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle this (given that this has to work with .Net Framework 4.8, so the new null-related code annotations are not available)?

Comment: Afaik, you can define [nullable analysis attributes](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Diagnostics/CodeAnalysis/NullableAttributes.cs) internally in your project and use them

Comment: What about `new()` constraint, is it possible to use in your scenario?